# How can you access Undertale Game Files on a PS4?

Tags: ps4, undertale

I saw that you can change your fun value, So I'll need to access the game files but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible as the PS4 save data hasn't really been cracked yet, and it's different from the PC edition data.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do it is to load your Undertale Safe Files on an external harddrive and edit the Files on your Pc!

- **Step 1:** Turn on TV and PS4
- **Step 2:** Insert External Harddrive
- **Step 3:** In the Main Menu, Go to "Settings"
- **Step 4:** Click on "Application Saved Data Management"
- **Step 5:** Select "Saved Data in System Storage"
- **Step 6:** Select "Copy to USB Storage Device"
- **Step 7:** Select Game to Copy
- **Step 8:** Wait Until Transfer Is Complete and remove the harddrive
- **Step 9:** Insert External Harddrive into your Pc and open up the Undertale folder

Open up undertale.ini with Notepad. Change the number listed next to "fun" into the desired number. Close the document, and save changes.

Then open up file0 with Notepad. Change line 36 of file0 in the same folder to the same number.

Comment: Have you tried this? If not how do you know that it works? I'm not saying it doesn't work but I'd think it wouldn't be as simple as opening notepad.

Comment: @DJSpicyDeluxe nah, its the same on pc, and the files are the exact same, there's just the extra files to enable compatibility for controller etc, etc. the actual game files themselves are the same, and you would normally 'just open notepad' on a PC.

Comment: @GoneBoyGone I would very much like to see some evidence such as a video or something...which could also improve this answer

Comment: @DJSpicyDeluxe unfortunately I do not own Undertale PS4, but I own PC Undertale, so I would think it would be the same process tbh..

Comment: @XxHarvzBackxX are you sure? I know it is simple to edit a *.ini* but **hard drives connected to a PS4 have to be formatted for it and in this process it overwrites the hard drive, meaning that IF it is possible, you would at least have to get software on your computer IF the hard drive data format has even been cracked.**

Comment: @Penguin assuming the drive is formatted correctly them you should have no problem connecting an external device afterwards and opening it using a simple tool like file explorer? unsure as to whether the files will be formatted in a way that a windows could understand but maybe a linux VM?

Comment: @XxHarvzBackxX PlayStation drives are formatted specially, as I said